# SQL Server Date Range Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am working with an Azure SQL Database.

I have a problem where I have to join to where the matching value is based on a date falling within a date range. I have two tables which have a parent/child relationship. The parent is `TBL_BOX`, the child is `TBL_ITEM` where the join is on `BOX_ID`. There is a log of the status of the BOX_ID in the table `TBL_BOX_STATUS` where there is a start date of `EFF_DATETIME` and an end date of `EXP_DATETIME`. The `TBL_ITEM` table has a log table of the values the the ITEM_IDs map to. This table also has a start date of `EFF_DATETIME` and an end date of `EXP_DATETIME`.

I have to be able to define a `@QUERY_DATE` of any DATETIME and be able to return the the boxes that did not have a status of 'DELETED' and the `ITEM_VALUE` that the `ITEM_ID` was mapped to at that time. I have provided a query for generating test data.

```
CREATE TABLE #NUMBERS 
(
    N INT
);

INSERT INTO #NUMBERS
SELECT TOP (1000000) 
    n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX N ON #NUMBERS(N);

CREATE TABLE #TBL_BOX 
(
    BOX_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BOX_ALT_ID NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #TBL_BOX (BOX_ALT_ID)
SELECT
    N
FROM #NUMBERS
WHERE 
    N <= 10000;

CREATE TABLE #TBL_ITEM
(
    ITEM_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ITEM_ALT_ID NVARCHAR(50),
    BOX_ID INT
);

INSERT INTO #TBL_ITEM (ITEM_ALT_ID, BOX_ID)
SELECT
    N AS ITEM_ALT_ID,
    CEILING(CAST(N AS FLOAT) / 50.0) AS BOX_ID
FROM #NUMBERS
WHERE 
    CEILING(CAST(N AS FLOAT) / 50.0) <= 10000;

CREATE TABLE #TBL_BOX_STATUS
(
    BOX_STATUS_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BOX_ID INT,
    BOX_STATUS NVARCHAR(50),
    EFF_DATETIME DATETIME,
    EXP_DATETIME DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #TBL_BOX_STATUS (BOX_ID, BOX_STATUS, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
BOX_ID,
'CREATED',
'2016-01-01',
'2016-01-02'
FROM #TBL_BOX;

INSERT INTO #TBL_BOX_STATUS (BOX_ID, BOX_STATUS, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
BOX_ID,
'READY',
'2016-01-02',
'9999-12-31'
FROM #TBL_BOX
WHERE
    BOX_ID <= 9000;

INSERT INTO #TBL_BOX_STATUS (BOX_ID, BOX_STATUS, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
BOX_ID,
'DELETED',
'2016-01-02',
'9999-12-31'
FROM #TBL_BOX
WHERE
    BOX_ID > 9000;

CREATE TABLE #TBL_ITEM_VALUE
(
    ITEM_VALUE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ITEM_ID INT,
    ITEM_VALUE NVARCHAR(50),
    EFF_DATETIME DATETIME,
    EXP_DATETIME DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #TBL_ITEM_VALUE (ITEM_ID, ITEM_VALUE, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
ITEM_ID,
'A',
'2016-01-01',
'2016-01-02'
FROM #TBL_ITEM
WHERE ITEM_ID <= 1000;

INSERT INTO #TBL_ITEM_VALUE (ITEM_ID, ITEM_VALUE, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
ITEM_ID,
'B',
'2016-01-02',
'9999-12-31'
FROM #TBL_ITEM
WHERE ITEM_ID <= 1000;

INSERT INTO #TBL_ITEM_VALUE (ITEM_ID, ITEM_VALUE, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME)
SELECT
ITEM_ID,
'A',
'2016-01-01',
'9999-12-31'
FROM #TBL_ITEM
WHERE ITEM_ID > 1000;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIDX_TBL_ITEM_VALUE ON #TBL_ITEM_VALUE (ITEM_ID, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME) INCLUDE (ITEM_VALUE);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIDX_TBL_BOX_STATUS ON #TBL_BOX_STATUS (BOX_ID, EFF_DATETIME, EXP_DATETIME) INCLUDE (BOX_STATUS);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIDX_TBL_ITEM_BY_ITEM ON #TBL_ITEM (ITEM_ID, BOX_ID);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIDX_TBL_ITEM_BY_BOX ON #TBL_ITEM (BOX_ID, ITEM_ID);
```

And here is the query that I need to be fast. I am looking for what would be the best indexing scheme for this or a better way to compose this query. I am also open to refactoring these tables. I can modify them if necessary. The project I am working on requires extensive logging of the change in values and being able to query the database with a `@QUERY_DATE AS DATETIME` parameter which defines the moment in time we are wanting to observe the state. The use of beginning and end date columns is the best thing I have come across but I am open to different schemes if it provides better performance. And now the query:

```
DECLARE @QUERY_DATE AS DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT
BX.BOX_ID,
ITM.ITEM_ID,
IV.ITEM_VALUE
FROM #TBL_BOX AS BX
JOIN #TBL_BOX_STATUS AS BS 
    ON BX.BOX_ID = BS.BOX_ID AND BS.EFF_DATETIME <= @QUERY_DATE AND BS.EXP_DATETIME > @QUERY_DATE
JOIN #TBL_ITEM AS ITM
    ON BS.BOX_ID = ITM.BOX_ID
JOIN #TBL_ITEM_VALUE AS IV
    ON ITM.ITEM_ID = IV.ITEM_ID AND IV.EFF_DATETIME <= @QUERY_DATE AND IV.EXP_DATETIME > @QUERY_DATE
WHERE
    BS.BOX_STATUS != 'DELETED'
```

**Update 2016-06-05**
I would like to constrain the complexity of this problem. When querying the state tables there is only ever a single Date value being considered. I do not need the full complexity of interval queries. I only ever have a single date being considered and there is only ever one match. For a given BOX_ID or ITEM_ID there is only one BOX_STATUS or ITEM_VALUE that matches. Date ranges do not overlap for a given BOX_ID or ITEM_ID. I don't know if that enables a better solution than what I have here but I wanted to constrain the scope.

Comment: Make all the identity all PK clustered

Comment: If I would like to get the best performance the I would start with Itzik Ben-Gan's article on range queries: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/sql-server-interval-queries. It has one implementation of RI-tree. Also, please see [this](http://sqlmag.com/database-development/optimization-tips-multiple-range-predicates-part-1) and [this](http://sqlmag.com/database-development/optimization-tips-multiple-range-predicates-part-2).

Comment: @Paparazzi: Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the example with Primary Keys. The real tables I am working with had these. I just forgot to include them in the example.

Comment: I am not seeing a purpose to BOX_STATUS_ID

Comment: @Paparazzi: All it is doing is providing a unique value for the row.

Comment: And what value is that?

Comment: Nothing other than making the row unique

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: Thank you for the information. I'm reading up on it. It would seem that SQL Server would have some kind of native support for this since interval searching would be a rather common use case.

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, your database design seems perfectly fine to me (but it's hard to tell without full context). There isn't necessarily a single 'right answer' in such matters, and the use of beginning and end dates like in your tables is a perfectly common approach in my experience.

When optimising a SQL query for performance, it's really important to look at the query plan being generated. That is usually something to do before you begin to add non-clustered indexes to relevant tables: the query plan should be your guide as to which indexes are worth adding.

In the absence of a query plan (NB I don't have a SQL box available to generate your test data on), and looking just at your main query, I suspect it may be possible to speed things up simply by breaking the query down into more stages, like this:

```
DECLARE @QUERY_DATE DATETIME = GETDATE();

WITH cteACTIVE_BOXES as (
  SELECT  DISTINCT
          BOX_ID
  FROM    TBL_BOX_STATUS
  WHERE   EFF_DATETIME <= @QUERY_DATE 
  AND     EXP_DATETIME > @QUERY_DATE
  AND     BOX_STATUS != 'DELETED'
  )
  ,cteACTIVE_ITEM_VALUE as (
  SELECT  DISTINCT 
          ITEM_ID
          ,ITEM_VALUE
  FROM    TBL_ITEM_VALUE
  WHERE   EFF_DATETIME <= @QUERY_DATE 
  AND     EXP_DATETIME > @QUERY_DATE
  )
SELECT      BX.BOX_ID
            ,ITM.ITEM_ID
            ,IV.ITEM_VALUE
FROM        TBL_BOX               AS BX
INNER JOIN  TBL_ITEM              AS ITM    ON BX.BOX_ID = ITM.BOX_ID
INNER JOIN  cteACTIVE_BOXES       AS BS     ON BX.BOX_ID = BS.BOX_ID 
INNER JOIN  cteACTIVE_ITEM_VALUE  AS IV     ON ITM.ITEM_ID = IV.ITEM_ID 
;
```

(I've adjusted the formatting to suit my own preference as I worked on the query.)

By defining the date-related restrictions on `TBL_BOX_STATUS` and `TBL_ITEM_VALUE` first, in separate sets, you can ensure that the final main query is operating on the smallest number of rows (and columns) necessary. It also makes the joins simpler and makes it easier (at least for me) to see what the most suitable indexes are to apply to these tables.

I'm using two CTEs here primarily because it's the simplest way to demonstrate what I mean. The approach I'm recommending could be implemented equally with table variables, temporary tables, or additional 'proper' tables used simply as a staging point (and cleared down after use). Which of these is most appropriate will depend partly on the amounts of data in your production environment, and on how you intend to use this query (e.g. as an ad-hoc query, inside a Stored Proc, etc...).

My use of the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the CTEs is partly a hedge: it may not be necessary and, if it was me, I would experiment on real data to determine if it has any use before including it in production code. However it could be helpful to the query performance if it allows SQL Server to guarantee uniqueness of the final joins.